# Median of 3 Quicksort in C

Tags: beginner, c, reinventing-the-wheel, quick-sort

I'm trying to re-implement the C stdlib function qsort using a [median of 3 quicksort.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559608/median-of-three-values-strategy)

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nitems, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void*))
```

This is my first major project in C, and I'd like to know how my style looks and what techniques I might be missing out on. Thanks for the help.

In `sort.h`, I have

```
/* returns > 0 if arg1 is greater than arg2, 0 if equal, < 0 if less*/
typedef int (*compare_func)(void *, void *);
/*Median of 3 quicksort Function*/
void quick_sort(void * arr, size_t nitems, size_t size,  compare_func compare);
```

And in `quick_sort.c` I have

```
#include "sort.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>    

void swap_mem(void * ptr1, void * ptr2, size_t size){
    /*
     * Swaps the values at the addresses pointed at by ptr1 and ptr2
     */
    void * tmp = malloc(size);
    memcpy(tmp, ptr1, size);
    memcpy(ptr1, ptr2, size);
    memcpy(ptr2, tmp, size);
    free(tmp);
}

void median_of_3(void * arr, size_t start, size_t stop, size_t size, compare_func compare){
    /*
     * Performs median of 3 partitioning on an array starting at start and ending
     * at stop
     */
    int mid;

    /*determine midpoint of array to nearest integer multiple of size*/
    mid = ((start + stop)>>1)/size * size;

    /*sort the 3 item array by comparing middle value to first and last value*/
    if(compare(arr + stop, arr + start) < 0)
        swap_mem(arr + stop, arr + start, size);
    if(compare(arr + mid, arr + start) < 0)
        swap_mem(arr + mid, arr + start, size);
    if(compare(arr + stop, arr + mid) < 0)
        swap_mem(arr + stop, arr + mid, size);

    /*swap the second to last value of arr with the median value*/
    swap_mem(arr + mid, arr + stop - size, size);
}

void quick_sort_aux(void * arr, size_t start, size_t stop, size_t size, compare_func compare){
    /*
     * Recursive median-of-3 quick sort
     */

    /*Base Case 1: 1 item in array (already sorted)*/
    if(start >= stop) return;

    /*Base Case 2: sort 2 or 3 item array*/
    median_of_3(arr, start, stop, size, compare);

    if(stop - start <=2*size) return;

    /*Recursively sort larger arrays*/
    int l_ptr = start;
    int r_ptr = stop - 2*size;

    /*move all values to the proper side of the pivot*/
    while(l_ptr <= r_ptr){
        while(compare(arr + l_ptr, arr + stop - size) < 0 && l_ptr <= r_ptr)
            l_ptr+=size;
        while(compare(arr + r_ptr, arr + stop - size) >= 0 && l_ptr <= r_ptr)
            r_ptr-= size;
        if(l_ptr <= r_ptr)
            swap_mem(arr + l_ptr, arr + r_ptr,size);
    }
    /*swap the pivot back into place*/
    swap_mem(arr + l_ptr, arr + stop - size,size);

    /*recursively sort the two halves*/
    quick_sort_aux(arr, start, l_ptr - size, size, compare);
    quick_sort_aux(arr, l_ptr + size, stop, size, compare);
}

void quick_sort(void * arr, size_t nitems, size_t size,  compare_func compare){
    /*
     * wrapper for recursive quick_sort_aux
     */
    quick_sort_aux(arr, 0, size*(nitems-1), size, compare);
}
```

This is my first time posting to StackExchange. Let me know how I can improve my question.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you receive great answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `swap_mem` will get called O(n log n) times. This makes it worth taking a closer look at for optimization.

One thing you can do is avoid repeated calls to `malloc` and `free` and instead preallocate the tmp buffer in the root function call and pass it around or use `alloca` to allocate the buffer on the stack.

```
void swap_mem(void * ptr1, void * ptr2, size_t size){
    /*
     * Swaps the values at the addresses pointed at by ptr1 and ptr2
     */
    void * tmp = alloca(size); //will get freed automatically on function exit.
    memcpy(tmp, ptr1, size);
    memcpy(ptr1, ptr2, size);
    memcpy(ptr2, tmp, size);
}
```